# how to make different string value for 0,01

Tags: c#, string

So recently i have asked a question for the same code , so this time i have issue with decimals. the thing is how can i make 0,01 use different value from 1 when my return works with n/10,100,100.. and so on i tried with
iplementing new variable that equals 0,01 made and if but still gave me the old result

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    // OT VIKTOR BOTKOV 304sr
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Въведете число.....:");
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        number = ConvertAmount(double.Parse(number));
        Console.WriteLine("Числото изписано в думи е : \n{0}", number);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static String[] units = { "нула", "едно", "две", "три",
"четири", "пет", "шест", "седем", "осем", "девет", "десет", "единайсет",
"дванайсет", "тринайсет", "четиринайсет", "петнайсет", "шеснайсет",
"седемнайсет", "осемнайсет", "деветнайсет" };
private static String[] tens = { "", "", "двайсет", "трийсет", "четиресет",
"педесет", "шейсет", "седемдесет", "осемдесет", "деведесет" };
private static String[] hundreds = {"","сто", "двеста", "триста","четиристотин",
"петстотин", "шестстотин", "седемстотин", "осемстотин", "деветстотин" };
private static String[] thousands = {"","хиляда","две хиялди", "три хиляди","четири хиляди",
"пет хиляди", "шест хиляди", "седем хиляди", "осем хиляди", "девет хиляди" };
private static String[] unitsс = { "нула ", "един", "два", };



public static String ConvertAmount(double amount)
{
    try
    {
        double mn = 0.09;
        Int64 amount_int = (Int64)amount;
        Int64 amount_dec = (Int64)Math.Round((Decimal)(amount - (double)(amount_int)) * 100);
        if (amount_dec == 0)
        {
            return Convert(amount_int) + " лв.";
        }
        else if (amount_int <= mn)
        {
            return Convert(amount_int) + " Цяло и " + " Нула " + Convert(amount_dec) + " ст.";
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert(amount_int) + " лв. и " + Convert(amount_dec) + " ст.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return "";
}

public static String Convert(Int64 i)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
  
    if (i<=2)
    {
        return unitsс[i];
    }
    if (i < 20)
    {
        return units[i];
    }
    if (i < 100)
    {
        return tens[i / 10] + ((i % 10 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 10) : "");
    }
    if (i < 1000)
    {
        return hundreds[i / 100] + ((i % 100 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 100) : "");
    }
    if (i < 100000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 1000) + " Хиляди "
                    + ((i % 1000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000) : "");
    }
    else if (i < 1000000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 10000) + " Хиляди "
                + ((i % 10000 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 10000) : "");
    }
    if (i < 10000000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? " " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
    }
    if (i < 100000000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
    }
    if (i < 1000000000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
    }
    if (i < 10000000000)
    {
        return Convert(i / 1000000000) + " Милиaрда "
                + ((i % 1000000000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000000000) : "");
    }
    return Convert(i / 1000000000000) + "  "
                + ((i % 1000000000000 > 0) ? " " + Convert(i % 10000000000000) : "");
}
```

it says zero point zero one i want the result to be zero point zero first and keep the value of 1 = one

Comment: well I would say extend the method `public static String Convert(Int64 i)` to `public static String Convert(Int64 i, bool isDecimalPlaces)` and in the method use `if (isDecimalPlaces)` to produce a different output

Comment: so i did try it and it doesnt work when i did the extended static string the convert everywhere was underlined red saying : There is no argument coresponds to the require parameter (i've tried including it with the if still the same)

Comment: if somebody feels like it, you can contact me in discord i can share screen and try to explain it best. My discord - Bocho#7914

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, if you want different outputs when dealing with decimal places and whole numbers the most straight forward solution would be to introduce a new arguemnt to your method to distinguish between them.

So change the method

```
public static String Convert(Int64 i)
```

To this:

```
public static String Convert(Int64 i, bool isDecimalPlaces)
```

In this method check this boolean and return the desired values for exmple, instead of

```
if (i<=2)
{
    return unitsс[i];  
}
if (i < 20)
{
    return units[i];
}
```

You may want to do this:

```
if (i<=2)
{
    if (isDecimalPlaces)
        return unitscDecimalPlaces[i];

    return unitsс[i];
}
if (i < 20)
{
    if (isDecimalPlaces)
        return unitsDecimalPlaces[i];

    return units[i];
}
```

Since we are accessing different arrays in the condition of `isDecimalPlaces == true`, you need to declare the different values for this branch

```
private static String[] unitsDecimalPlaces = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4",
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12",
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
"18", "19" };
private static String[] unitsсDecimalPlaces = { "0 ", "1", "2", };

//Notice I have used numeric values, since I don't know russian (I am assuming this is the language, sorry if I am wrong)
```

Here a complete example of the idea
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vqhfb9

Comment: Thank you again i will try it P.S its Bulgarian just its tricky with the numbers